# Resize canvas of svg images in command line

Tags: svg, command-line, imagemagick, inkscape

I have bunch of svg images (1.svg 2.svg ...) and i would like to center them and resize canvas to the same value for all of them. Let's say that image 1.svg has w. 600 and h. 800 and 2.svg has w. 1000 and h. 400. I would like to set canvas for both as 1000x800 and center images. As the result the images won't be resized, but they will have extra space on sides -> 1.svg will still be 600x800 but in canvas with size 1000x800 and 2.svg will be 1000x400 but in canvas with size 1000x800. Is it possible to do in command line? Using inkscape, imagemagick etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do that with **ImageMagick** but, as it is a raster image processor, you will get a rasterised (bitmap) image out (i.e. a PNG, or GIF or JPEG) and not a vector image (i.e. SVG). Is that what you want?

Comment: PNG image is definitely fine, I just need to obtain same size of canvas with conserving the size of original image inside this canvas and because of lot of files I need to do it in batch.

Comment: I’m actually very interested in a solution with an SVG output. I frequently get sets of SVG icons of which sizes I need to normalize for web sites integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `-extent` option to **ImageMagick**, like this:

```
convert 1.svg -gravity center -background yellow -extent 1000x800 result.png
```

So, let's make some images:

```
convert -size 600x800! xc:red 1.png
convert 1.png -gravity center -background yellow -extent 1000x800 result.png
```

[image]

Or the other way:

```
convert -size 1000x400! xc:red 2.png
convert 2.png -gravity center -background blue -extent 1000x800 result.png
```

[image]